# Springboot with Elastic search XContent conflict

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

Im having a java micro-servcie working with Elasticsearch and was working great, I decided to move it to Springboot and all good except one problem that I was facing for hours and can't find any solution online.

```
java: cannot access org.elasticsearch.xcontent.ToXContentObject
  class file for org.elasticsearch.xcontent.ToXContentObject not found
```

I gave it a try to play with the versions here and there based on some some advices but still. I also check the maven tree and can't see any elastic search stuff injected from Springboot. Any one can help on this plz?

my pom dependencies are :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hawaya.libraries</groupId>
        <artifactId>enums</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hawaya.libraries</groupId>
        <artifactId>configuration-manager</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
        <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>7.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.16</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>7.17.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
        <version>8.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
                <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    <version>7.17.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.34.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
        <version>1.115.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20200518</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.22</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test Dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0-M1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded the springboot version from 2.6.3 to 3.0.2 and its now working fine :)

Answer (score -1):

I think you are just declared a lot of redundant artifacts in pom.xml that is related to Elastic so there is a conflicts between dependecies.
Try to use just this ones:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opensearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>opensearch</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opensearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>opensearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

At least it is working in my project.

Comment: Thanks a lot, are you sure the version is 1.3.0? also I think there is a typo its "elasticsearch" not "opensearch"

Comment: Opensearch is a fork of elasticsearch so you can use that one that fits your needs better and select appropriate version. My answer is just example that you most likely you need only two dependencies out of all.